# Decode Hash::MultiValue inplace in perl

Tags: perl

Having an [Hash::MultiValue](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::MultiValue) object. The `keys` and `values` could be utf8 encoded byte-strings. Need decode them *inplace*.

The following does what I want:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Hash::MultiValue;
use Encode;

my $hm = make_demo_data(); # the $hm is Hash::MultiValue
                           # the keys and values are utf8 encoded byte-strings
$hm->each(sub { print "$_[0]: $_[1]\n" });

decodehm($hm); #decode the $hm inplace

say "--decoded--";    
binmode(STDOUT, ':utf8');
$hm->each(sub { print "$_[0]: $_[1]\n" });

sub decodehm {
    my $hm = shift;
    #make copy - but decoded
    my $new = Hash::MultiValue->new( map Encode::decode_utf8($_), $hm->flatten );
    $hm->clear; #clear the original
    $new->each( sub { $hm->add($_[0], $_[1]) });    #set each element in the original $hm
}

sub make_demo_data { #utf8 encoded byte-strings
    return Hash::MultiValue->new(
        "k1\x{c3}\x{a1}" => "v1a\x{c3}\x{a1}",
        "k1\x{c3}\x{a1}" => "v1b\x{c3}\x{a1}",
        "k2a" => "v2aa",
        "k3\x{c3}\x{a1}" => "v3a\x{c3}\x{a1}",
    );
}
```

eg. on the utf8 terminal prints the wanted result

```
k1á: v1aá
k1á: v1bá
k2a: v2aa
k3á: v3aá
--decoded--
k1á: v1aá
k1á: v1bá
k2a: v2aa
k3á: v3aá
```

but the sub `decodehm` - isn't "nice". Is possible solve the problem in more "elegant" form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking if you can change the key (i.e. decode it) without removing the original element and reinserting it. If so, the answer is no. For hashes, a mathematical function (the hashing function) converts the key into an index. Changing the key can change the index, so changing the key requires moving the value from the old index to the new index, so changing the key requires removal and reinsertion of the value.